# C TCP cannot detect broken connection

Tags: c, sockets, ip, tcp

I have basic tcp application written in C. It basically sends data to a tcp server. I have connected two PC's with cross cable. I send data from one, and successfully get this data from another one. I have built this mechanism to test If somehow connection broken by unhealty ways (ruptured cable etc.), I want to be informed as client. But things doesn't work as I wanted.If I manually stop tcpserver, client side is informed, but when I start program, connection establishes, data starts to flow, then I unplug the cable, and both sides behaves like nothing happened. Client still sends data with no error, and server still shows the client connected but data flow stops. After a few minutes, I plug cable again, the datas -which considered as sent but not sent- flushes suddenly then program continues normally. How can I detect a broken connection like this? Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code;

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
const char* server_name = "192.168.5.2";
const int server_port = 30152;

struct sockaddr_in server_address;
memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;

// creates binary representation of server name
// and stores it as sin_addr
// http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html
inet_pton(AF_INET, server_name, &server_address.sin_addr);

// htons: port in network order format
server_address.sin_port = htons(server_port);

// open a stream socket
int sock;
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("could not create socket\n");
    return 1;
}

// TCP is connection oriented, a reliable connection
// **must** be established before any data is exchanged
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
            sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
    printf("could not connect to server\n");
    return 1;
}

// send

// data that will be sent to the server
const char* data_to_send = "HELLO THIS IS DATA!";
while(1)
{
    int err = send(sock, data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send), 0);

    if(err==-1)
    {
        printf("ERROR \n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sent  \n");
        sleep(1);
    }

}
printf("EOP\n");

// close the socket
close(sock);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do more tests with a longer time. TCP can take many minutes before it timesout the TCP connection and errors out. Give it 10-15 minutes and measure and measure the time until your send() call errors out.

Comment: Keepalive can help you to detect broken links (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)

Comment: @qrdl thank you I think it will work

Comment: Reduce the send buffer size with setsockopt() and you will be notified in advance with a write/send failure or by a select() informing socket not ready for write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the peer of a TCP connection closes the connection, it will lead to a `recv` call on your end to return `0`. That's the way to detect closed (but not broken) connections.

If you don't *currently* receive anything from the peer, you need to make up a protocol on top of TCP which includes receiving data.

Furthermore, sending might not detect broken connections (like missing cables etc.) directly, as there are a lot of retransmissions and timeouts. The best way is again to implement some kind of protocol overlaying TCP, one that for example contains a kind of "are you there" message which expects a reply. If a reply to the "are you there" message isn't received within some specific timeout, then consider the connection broken and disconnect.